# how to create single layout that will look same on vertical and horizontal layout using constraints layout in android

Tags: android-layout

I am using constraint layout and i am a beginner ,can anyone help me for creating a single layout that will look same on both horizontal and vertical view,i have created this but this is looking different on view.
**Do i need to create separate layout for both?**

**My code of xml for 5 inch screen:-**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:padding="16dp"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<android.support.constraint.Guideline
    android:id="@+id/guideline"
    android:layout_width="1dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.5"/>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button2"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Button"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    android:layout_marginTop="53dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button3"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Button"
    android:layout_marginTop="85dp"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/button2"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button4"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Button"
    android:layout_marginTop="88dp"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/button3"
    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0" />

<android.support.constraint.Guideline
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/guideline2"
    app:layout_constraintGuide_begin="1097dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use code like this

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:padding="16dp"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/button3"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button3"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/button4"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/button2" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button4"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/button3" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

This should work on both screen orientations.

**NOTE**

With `ConstraintLayout`, using the layout editor is far easier than using the text editor.

Comment: @Sunil First, your code uses hardcoded values as `marginTop` parameters to bring the buttons to the center. While this might work for your device, it most certainly wouldn't look the same on devices of different sizes or orientations.